# Why isn't this list/scrollview filling the parent?

Tags: android, listview, fullscreen

I was following some instructions here: http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

The example I'm following shows the list fullscreen.  That's what I want mine to do.  What am I doing wrong?

examples result: [image: examples result]

My result:

[image: my result]

The example I followed used 2 xml layouts.  1 for the page.  1 for the list.

The page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000fff"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
<TextView  android:id="@id/android:empty"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:background="#FFff00"
android:text="No data"
/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here's the xml for the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvAccountName"         
android:textSize="16sp"         
android:textStyle="bold" 
android:textColor="#FFFF00"        
android:layout_width="fill_parent"         
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvAccountType" 
android:typeface="sans"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textStyle="italic"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/tvAccountBalance"         
android:textSize="12sp"         
android:textStyle="bold"      
android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the entry from the manifest:

```
   <activity android:name=".listAccountsPage"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.ourcreditunion.ourcumobile.LISTACCOUNTS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

So what did I do to cause it to not be full screen?

Comment: You have a ListView inside of a ScrollView. Don't do that. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @adamp says - don't put a listview inside a scrollview. Which one is going go scroll?
Your xml needs to be simpler also. Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want a colored background, set the background attribute in the RelativeLayout

Comment: I just put adamps suggestion in and it worked.  Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is coming from this

```
android:layout_weight="2"
```

in the declaration of the list view. The number given follows some inverse logic,
meaning that the larger it is, the smaller the view gets.